# Update PDF reading order using iText 7

Tags: itext, itext7

Here's my requirements:

1. Take an existing PDF/UA document with a defined reading order
2. Overlay some additional text on the document in multiple places
3. Update the reading order to properly reflect the additions

Requirements 1 and 2 have been solved. I'm stuck on #3. Is it possible to do this with iText and if so, can someone point me to a resource that shows how?